# Align a TextView right to the Horizontal Center

Tags: android, text-alignment, android-relativelayout

How do I align a `TextView` right to the Horizontal Center in a `RelativeLayout`?[image]

Okay. To make it more clear as someone asked me to.

```
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
```

This sets the text like in the image below, which I do not require.

[image]

I have got it working by using an extra `TextView`. Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHelper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMyText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewHelper"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="My Text" />
```

Comment: can u clearly mention what exactly u want

Comment: You just drag it to the right side in the xml designer,The point of using Relativelayout is that you can place views with respect to other views position. Or you can use a Linear Layout and assign gravity for the widget

Comment: @insomniac Yes I get that. I thought there might be some option that I am missing. Same as we have an option to align to the center directly without the help of any other view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this property  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `LinearLayout`.But you have to use 1 extra view.
*I don't know any other option.*

code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly how I make it work as of now. So there is no option to do this directly?

Comment: like I showed u. use linear layout and an extra view

Comment: @andro: u can't handle that if u use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: linear layout is not an option here. I have other views which depend on the position of this textView

Answer (score 0):

Create `LinearLayout` of horizontal orientation add two View in that having view weight 50% for each.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                    
        android:weightSum="2" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LinearLayout` like an invisible line at the middle of the `RelativeLayout`, and align your items `toRightOf`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this one

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Large Text" />
```

This makes the widget to align to the right side of the parent the other alignment options like these obviously are:- `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`,`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Another option using RelativeLayout: use a view with centerHorizontal to act as an anchor for the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anchor"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <!-- more views -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/anchor"` instead if you want to support right-to-left layouts.